# Java Exclusive Fullscreen Mode Keeps Throwing 'Invalid display mode'

Tags: java, fullscreen, illegalargumentexception

I can't for the life of me figure out Exlusive Fullscreen. It keeps throwing 'Invalid display mode' no matter which of my display modes I try.

I've tried doing this as the official Java tutorials show, and as other people's tutorials show. I keep getting the same error thrown. The try-finally, as suggested in the official Java tutorials, gives me the same issues. I've already made sure I'm using my supported modes.

Could this have something to do with my laptop's display being overclocked from 75Hz to 100Hz? I have of course tried supplying my own DisplayMode with DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN.

```java
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    private static GraphicsEnvironment gfxEnv;
    private static GraphicsDevice gfxDevice;
    private static DisplayMode defaultDisplayMode;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
    }

    private static void init() {
        gfxEnv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        gfxDevice = gfxEnv.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        defaultDisplayMode = gfxDevice.getDisplayMode();

        DisplayMode[] displayModes = gfxDevice.getDisplayModes();
        DisplayMode dm1920x1080x75 = displayModes[displayModes.length - 1];
        System.out.println(dm1920x1080x75);

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                aMethodIWantToCallElseWhere();
            }

        });
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        if (gfxDevice.isFullScreenSupported()) {
            gfxDevice.setFullScreenWindow(window);
            if (gfxDevice.isDisplayChangeSupported())
                gfxDevice.setDisplayMode(dm1920x1080x75);
        }
    }

    public static void aMethodIWantToCallElseWhere() {
        if (gfxDevice.isDisplayChangeSupported())
            gfxDevice.setDisplayMode(defaultDisplayMode);
        gfxDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
1920x1080x32bpp@75Hz

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid display mode
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.setDisplayMode(Win32GraphicsDevice.java:452)
    at Main.aMethodIWantToCallElseWhere(Main.java:48)
    at Main$1.keyTyped(Main.java:33)
    at...
```

This does enter fullscreen without any issues. But exiting it is where the problem appears. I've tried this in the suggested try-finally way, which throws the exact same error - 'Invalid display mode'.

I've played around with a bunch of different ideas, but I'm now out of them.
Am I missing something?

I'd like to avoid the try-finally, just so that I can change modes on user request. I hope that's possible.

EDIT
So I tried setting my display back from 100Hz to 75Hz. That solved it. How would I go about getting it running with an overclocked display that doesn't even appear in getDisplayModes?

Comment: On what operating system did this occur?  How did you change the refresh rate, exactly?

Comment: @VGR Windows 10. Nvidia control panel. Right click desktop and then just had a custom one added at 1920x1080x32bpp@100Hz. It always worked without issues, until just now when I realised it's messing up with Java exclusive fullscreen.

Comment: Do any of the modes returned by `getDisplayModes()` show 100 Hz, when your video is set to 100 Hz?  Perhaps the last one in the array is not always the “best” one?

Comment: I did iterate them all textually to be sure of course, and they all stick to 75Hz. No matter whether I set my refresh rate to 100Hz or 75Hz, it shows the same list of modes, all sticking with 75Hz. 
Checking the already set getDisplayMode() on init will also show a mode at 75Hz at all times.
I'm confident all I have to do is get it in the list of modes, as it is a necessity from what I've read...

Comment: So here's a screenshot showing my custom mode being in the list of my gpu's available modes. What I believe is happening is that Java picks the default list on the left, excluding the custom modes. Is this a correct assumption?

<https://imgur.com/XqZTnhM>

Comment: I honestly don’t know.  I would have thought Java would query a standard Windows API for currently available modes;  maybe it’s querying the wrong API.  It may be worth [filing a bug](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/).

Comment: I'll do that then. Thanks for the assistance!